# WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 Proxy Service issue : The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found

Tags: wso2, task, esb, endpoint, wso2-esb

Hello I tried to create a proxy "myfirst_proxy" that points to the following endpoint : test_myapp

this Endpoint is pointing to `http://server1/myapp/service/test.php?wsdl` ( I tested the url and it returned successful )

I created a sequence : log and drop and added it to the Out Sequence in the proxy config.

I added a scheduled task to run every 2 min after 9 just for the sake if testing:

```
 <task name="testtask" class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz">
    <trigger cron="0 0/2 9 * * ?"/>
    <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="message">
        <sendText xmlns=""/>
    </property>
    <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="to" value="http://myesbserver:8280/services/myfirst_proxy"/>
    <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="soapAction" value="urn:MYAPP#sendText"/>
    <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="format" value="soap11"/>
</task>
```

Now when I access `http://myesbserver:8280/services/myfirst_proxy`  I will get the following error : he endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/myfirst_proxy and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable

but when I add ?wsdl at the end I see the WSDL file.

in the Log file I see the following scheduled task been executed:

```
INFO - LogMediator To: http://myesbserver:8280/services/myfirst_proxy, WSAction: urn:MYAPP#sendText, SOAPAction: urn:SLATE#sendText, MessageID: urn:uuid:87b2695a-ce95-43fa-b7d2-3d638c3d5f20, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><sendApproval/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I checked the App Server if it received any request from ESB Proxy, it did not, I use the Try tool that comes with the ESB, I put the string   between the body tags and run it. the response was successful.

So my question, am I missing a step that would allow my task to talk to the remote WSDL ?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you provide your proxy configuration?

Comment: @Ratha Here is the Proxy config : `<proxy name="myfirst_proxy" transports="http" startOnLoad="true" trace="enable">
        <target endpoint="test_myapp" inSequence="log_and_drop" faultSequence="fault"/>
        <publishWSDL uri="http://server1/myapp/service/test.php?wsdl"/>
        <policy key="conf:/repository/axis2/service-groups/myfirst_proxy/services/myfirst_proxy/policies/RMPolicy"/>
        <parameter name="Action">sendText</parameter>
        <parameter name="interface">MYAPPPortType</parameter>
        <parameter name="serviceType">proxy</parameter>
        <enableRM/>
    </proxy>`

Comment: What is your endpoint configuartion?

Comment: `    <endpoint name="test_myapp">
        <address uri="http://server1/myapp/service/test.php?wsdl" statistics="enable" format="soap11"/>
    </endpoint>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define task like that..

```
 <task name="testtask" class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz">

    <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="to" value="http://myesbserver:8280/services/myfirst_proxy/getparam?a=1"/>  
        </task>
```

Then in the main sequence route that to proxy;

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="main">
   <in>
      <log level="full"/>
      <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              source="get-property('To')"
              regex=".*/myfirst_proxy.*">
         <then>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
            <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
            <log level="custom">
               <property name="***********MESSAGE******" value="executing myfirst Proxy Sequence"/>
            </log>
            <send/>
            <drop/>
         </then>
         <else/>
      </filter>
```

Comment: So in the proxy config  should I add "main" as in or out sequence ?  I got kind of confused, I would say out sequence. thanks again

Comment: "What getparam?a=1 " just for example..You don't need to define main sequence as your out sequence..It is to route task message to proxy..you can define your custom sequence as your outsequence.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your endpoint url is wrong..It should point the actual service endpoint..Not the wsdl url..
May be it is like;

```
http://server1/myapp/service/test.php
```

Comment: that must be a mistake when I copied the URL, I changed that, I looked at the endpoint access_log, I couldn't see any activity coming from ESB, Entering the URL http://myesbserver:8280/services/myfirst_proxy in the browser it give a connection reset and I could see the following entry in the access log : `..."GET /myapp/service/test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4936 "-" "Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO"`, when I add ?wsdl it would display the wsdl file.

Comment: I added full configuration to have more visibility  http://pastebin.com/P1svUY2s  thanks for your help

Comment: When you send a GET request to your proxy, please check that particular get operation is present in the WSDL you provided in the proxy as well as at your actual back end service .

Comment: It is present because I tested it using SoapUI and also with the tool that comes with ESB, it does grab the message that I m sending, but when I try to schedule a task to call the proxy it won't even reach the server, . I m not sure if it has to do with the sequence. I configured the sequence to do a Log and Send, correct me if I m wrong. I don't see any Error messages within the logs although I set it to Trace, Debug etc.. and I run a tcpdump on the other server, All I see the packets from ESB when I save changes within the proxy or testing the remote WSDL.

Comment: Oh..sorry..you can not call proxy from task..you have to send it via main sequence..check my 2nd ans for smaple